# Websocket saturation in Chrome, blob points to data which does not exist

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket, protocols, filereader

I've got one of this very difficult to debug problems in my app.

I'm using websockets to receive images from my server. I'm getting around 50 images per second in binary and showing them in a canvas as image.

Everything works ok, but **sometimes I'm getting an error**:

```
FileReader error. Name: NotFoundError Message: A requested file or directory could not be found at the time an operation was processed.
```

My code looks like this:

```
wsVisualizerManager.onMessage = function(e)
{
    if (e.data instanceof Blob)
    {

        var blob = e.data;
        this.reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);

    }

}
```

Basically **I get a blob and I read it with a FileReader object** (this.reader) to be able to visualize it as an image.

As I said everything works, but sometimes, **seems that due to receive more images that the ones it can handle** I start getting this error.

When I start getting this error I don't get it once, **I get it many times**, so my app is blocked during a lot of time. If I launch chrome development tools the error stops immediately and my app works again (so maybe this developer tool is cleaning some buffers?).

So, I guess that It is some kind of buffer which get completely full, but the think is that If I have to lose old messages I'm ok with that, but why calling onMessage with a bad formated or inexistent blob?

I don't know exactly how to debug this error, because websocket API has just a few methods and no one allows me to access a buffer or clean it.

**A way of generate this error manually** (otherwise I get it just twice a day) is putting one breakpoint just at the beginning of onMessage and wait some time. What happens then is that when I press play I start getting this error and after some seconds I start receiving retarded images. So seems that it's not removing the received images or at least not all of them.

I'm developing the server part too. And I'm using C++ with the library websocket++. And my chrome version is: 43.0.2357.125 (64-bit)

Any clue of how to proceed debugging this error or trying to solve the problem?